# Does Firebase Database offer features like Events, Triggers and Stored Procedures?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question in regards to the capabilities of Firebase in equivalence to MySQL features like:

- Events
- Triggers
- Stored Procedures

In my case I want to migrate off of MySQL to Firebase but I need to know if the usecase can be replicated in Firebase.

My current MySQL DB I have a table that has a column called status which once it  gets changed to 'Final' it triggers the execution of a stored procedure to do a calculation on an entire table.

So in other words I would have to be able to add a 'trigger' on the actual firebase data to then perform a 'stored procedure' to calculate something; is this possible with Firebase?!

Comment: well, for starters, Firebase is No-SQL, so your migration will require additional work. I'm in a very similar situation, and the official documentation is very ambiguous and little covered to my taste :(

Comment: @Famic : Did you get your solution? I am in a same situation.. I need to replace store procedure with firebase database. How can i do?

Comment: one solution can be running a server side app, listen tor child event and execute some scripts @ArpitPatel

Comment: Thanks @IftikarUrrhmanKhan. I just want to know one thing. How would i get result from the that script in all other clients(mobile, web and all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now have the capability to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write code that triggers in response to changes in your Firebase project.  There is lots of [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) that illustrates how to respond to writes to a particular location in your database, among many other types of events.